# STOP keyword + contact Delete request

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, contactbuilder

I have a question regarding the behaviour of STOP keyword with a contact Delete request in a Shared code environment :

**Use case 1 : Contact delete after STOP is sent by the Contact**

- A Contact CK1 is subscribed to a Keyword ABCD associated with a shared code 1234
- CK1 received an SMS on the Keyword ABCD
- CK1 replies STOP to the shared code
- CK1 is deleted from SFMC with the Contact Delete Process
- CK1 is reintroduced to SFMC and resubscribed to the keyword ABCD
- CK1 is injected to a journey with a Send SMS on the keyword ABCD

**Use case 2 : Contact delete before STOP is sent by the Contact**

- A Contact CK1 is subscribed to a Keyword ABCD associated with a shared code 1234
- CK1 received an SMS on the Keyword ABCD
- CK1 is deleted from SFMC with the Contact Delete Process
- CK1 replies STOP to the shared code
- CK1 is reintroduced to SFMC and resubscribed to the keyword ABCD
- CK1 is injected to a journey with a Send SMS on the keyword ABCD

**Question :**

In both use cases, will the contact CK1 receive the SMS ?
Will the send bounce and get added to the UndeliverableSMS Data view ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact CK1 in both use cases should receive the SMS.

**In Use Case 1:**
The 5th bullet reintroduces them back into the All Contacts list in [MobileConnect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_mobileconnect.htm&type=5) as Active. This allows the recipient to receive the SMS message in the Journey in the next bullet.

**In Use Case 2:**
The 4th bullet introduces the contact with the STOP keyword but changes that status to Active in the next bullet. Same as Use Case 1 above, it should allow the contact into the Journey to receive the SMS message.

Both cases should also allow bounces to be recorded in the [UndeliverableSMS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_undeliverable_sms.htm&type=5) data view.

Also the assumption is that you do not have double-opt in enabled which in both cases the contact won't receive the SMS message unless they first double-opt-in before being entered into the journey.